# Data validation on price PHP

Tags: php, validation, parsing

I have the following problem. I need to validate and possibly extract currency from a value that I have received. The trouble starts with the fact that the value can be received in any encoding. Additionally to make things worse I can receive a lot of different values that should be considered correct. Let me give an example

$ 123,123,233.00

123,123.99

123.123.123,99

123.123.123 $

All of these are correct.

What I've tried is adding three arrays:
1. Chars (",","."," ")
2. Digits(0-9)
3. Currency Signs($,€...)

Trouble started when the data came in UTF-8 and I can no longer perform search digit by digit on the value I've received as in UTF-8 Currency signs are multibyte.

Question is what to do !?

I've tried the following thing.

Search for a currency sign. Then replace it with nothing. For some unknown reason PHP only replaces the second byte of the multibyte representation of the currency sign and there is a mysterious sign in the string that fails the whole check.

Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: you should refer to http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: Can't you just strip out non-numeric characters?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so 100.00 becomes 10000 ?

Comment: You should always work with integers when dealing with currency anyway. Floats are not precise.

Answer (score 0):

Datelligent idea may actually be a good simple solution: you could replace every non numerical character except the ones useful for puntuaction, with this regex `\D*(?!\d{1,2}[\D$])`:

```
$price=preg_replace('\D*(?!\d{1,2}[\D$])', '', $price);
```

It would transform `1233,234 234.23` into `1233234234.23`.

Careful though, stuff like `123,2 34,234` would end up `123,2 34234`. It does assume that punctuation followed by three or more digits isn't relevant, doesn't account for potential typos, will delete the currency symbol, etc... but it may be relevant to the scope of your issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 $price=$_POST['price'];
 $price=preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $price);
```

This way **PHP** will remove all characters and give you a string containing only numbers,  which for handling prices is perfect.

If decimals are needed then modify the **RegEx** to get them:

```
$price=preg_replace('[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?', '', $price);
```

Comment: 100.00 becomes ten thousand

Comment: Modify the RegEx to this to catch decimals,   [0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?